# When is an algebra derived indecomposable?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, lie-algebras, derived-categories

Call a finite dimensional (acyclic) quiver $K$-algebra A derived indecomposable in case $A$ is not derived equivalent to an algebra of the form $B \otimes_K C$.

For example when the number of simples or the vector space dimension of $A$ is a prime number $A$ is derived indecomposble. But $K D_4$ is derived equivalent to $K A_2 \otimes_K KA_2$ and thus not derived indecomposable.
$KE_6$ is derived equivalent to $K A_2 \otimes_K K A_3$. $KE_8$ is derived equivalent to $K A_2 \otimes K A_4$.

> Question 1: Is there an (easy) criterion when a given algebra is derived indecomposable?

Easy could mean that it can be decided by some discrete data that are computable for example using QPA.

> Question 2: Is a derived equivalence like $K E_6$ to $K A_2 \otimes_K K A_3$ pure coincidence or is there more behind it? Can we also "build" $E_6$ up to some equivalences from $A_2$ and $A_3$ in other situations like Lie algebras?

> Question 3: For which acyclic graphs $Q$ is the path algebra $KQ$ derived indecomposable?

Comment: In singularity theory, one can make the simple singularity E6 ($x^3+y^4$) from A2 ($x^3$) and A3 ($y^4$). This sum-with-disjoint-variables is named the Thom–Sebastiani sum.

Comment: There is a necessary condition, that the Coxeter polynomial is a tensor product of two polynomials. This can be checked for instance on the set of roots.