# Tensor decomposition under derived equivalence

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $K$ be a field. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $K$-algebra and there is a derived equivalence $F:D^b(A)\cong D^b(B)$ between their bounded derived categories. If we assume that $A$ has a tensor decomposition $A\cong A_1\otimes_K A_2$ for two $K$-algebras $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Does $B$ also have a tensor decomposition $B\cong B_1\otimes_K B_2$ such that $D^b(B_1)\cong D^b(A_1)$ and $D^b(B_2)\cong D^b(A_2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in general.

For an easy example, let $C$ and $D$ be derived equivalent algebras. Then $A=C\times C$ and $B=C\times D$ are derived equivalent, and $A=C\otimes_K(K\times K)$ has a tensor decomposition, but $B$ will usually not.

There are also connected examples. For example, $KA_2\otimes_K KA_2$ is derived equivalent to $KD_4$ (where $KA_2$ and $KD_4$ are path algebras of quivers of the indicated Dynkin type).

There are more examples in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370535/when-is-an-algebra-derived-indecomposable). But also, examples are very easy to construct. If you take an algebra of the form $A=A_1\otimes_KA_2$, then it will usually have many tilting complexes, and unless you choose one of the form $T_1\otimes_KT_2$, there is no particular reason to expect its endomorphism algebra (which is derived equivalent to $A$) to have a tensor decomposition.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer.